# Hosting inhouse or in a Data center

Tags: seo, web-hosting

I have test application, which popularity would drive the business - its a portal to be used by 100's of people.

I am at a very start up of it and confused whether to host it on my inhouse server or pay a certain amount and host it online.

My application is SEO sensitive.

My question is whether it will affect SEO in anyway if

1. I host the application initially on my servers inhouse with lesser bandwidth and a bit dis-connectivity?
2. migrate to professional servers as the business grows?

Comment: Hosting inhouse is absolute madness nowadays. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely answering your question, Google doesn't know whether you hosted your site in-house or with a 3rd party hosting company and therefore, it wouldn't be biased to one or the other. However, if I server is whitelisted or blacklisted, that would increase/decrease your 'SEO Juice' if you will. For example, if you are put on a server that has been marked spam, search engines will ding you for it.

Besides that though, hosting is so cheap now, why not just let them deal with the server management, uptime, etc.? It's just a lot easier.

Comment: Seconded. You can run your own cloud servers or VPS for $20-$40 a month, and not have to worry about swapping out a burnt out motherboard in the middle of the night.

Comment: Yes. Hosting is cheap but I need a java tomcat hosting which is not that cheap and their are no providers (that I know) who provide atleast 1 day trial - they just provide money back gurantee and I have tried couple of them, but my application needs lot of setting on server - so buying a dedicated plan becomes costly even for trial. - So wanted to know whether slow internet speed will hurt SEO?

Comment: As mentioned in my original answer, no, internet speed won't effect your SEO. What do you consider expensive? You can get a VPS for about $50/month and again, the work you'll save and IT costs are well worth 4 times that.